# Calculation of variance

Tags: variance

Suppose E(X|Y) and that a figure illustrates expected salary as a function of gender and that it shows that the mean for women is $2500 \$$ and for men is $3500\$$. If $50\%$ are women and $50\%$ men, the variance is 250 000. How to get there, how to calculate the variance and plot the figure?

It is the variance in the means that are meant here.

Comment: This is not clear.  First of all, the units for variance should not be "dollars" here.  Secondly, there's nothing to calculate.  We are given the variance.  We have no information regarding the variance other than that raw value.

Comment: I edited the units of variance.

Comment: But the second part of my comment was more important.  We have no information about the variance other than the raw value, which was handed to us.  There is nothing to calculate.

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis about the genders' relative variances, e.g. that they're equal, or proportional to some power of the gender means?

Comment: If you have the raw data  (everybody's salary) then there is no difficulty calculating the variance, just from the definition.

Comment: I added to the body of the post a question; how to plot the figure?

Answer (score 0):

The random variable being discussed is a sample mean, conditioned over gender.

The mean of this sample mean is $(2500+3500)/2$ which is $3000$.

$$\mathsf E(\bar X)=\sum_x x\, \mathsf P(\bar X{=}x)$$

The variance of the sample mean is $((2500-3000)^2+(3500-3000)^2)/2$ which is $250\,000$.

$$\mathsf{Var}(\bar X)=\sum_x (x-\mathsf E(\bar X))^2\,\mathsf P(\bar X{=}x)$$